# inline style for mailadresses in HTML mail

Tags: html, css, email, hyperlink, html-email

I am sending emails with information about peoples and I've got one problem.
I am using a blue background and when there is an email in the text, I can not see it:

[image: Mail with text]

As you can see, I can't read the email behind it because it is a clickable link.
Since i am using this in a mail, I need inline CSS to fix this problem. 
The current HTML and CSS of the mail text:

```
<td style="box-sizing: border-box;color: #fff;padding: .75rem;vertical-align: top;border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;border: 0;font-family: &quot;Roboto&quot;, sans-serif !important;background-color: transparent!important; color: #fff !important; text-decoration: none !important;">mail@mail.com</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the email address within `td` cell is wrapped in an `a` tag by the email client to treat it as a hyperlink. You can explicitly add it yourself and apply specific inline styles there.

See below. I didn't touch anything on the containing `td` cell itself.

**html**

```
<a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;">
  mail@mail.com
</a>
```